# getting code to run upon widget creation flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter camera app and am able to get a recorded video to play.  The problem is, I am only able to get it to play when a button is pressed.  How do I get the code to run when the widget(screen) is created instead of when the button is pressed so I don't have to press a button to get it to play?  Here is my code:

Here is the code for when the button is pressed:

```
//raised button
    RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {stopButtonPressed();},

//stopButtonPressed
void stopButtonPressed() {
          print('stopButtonPressed hit');
          stopVideoRecording().then((_) {
            print('StopVideoRecording complete');
          });
        }


//stopVideoRecording
Future<void> stopVideoRecording() async {
          print('stopVideoRecording hit');
          await _startVideoPlayer();
        }


//_startVideoPlayer

Future<void> _startVideoPlayer() async {
          print('_startVideoPlayer hit');
          print(Provider.of<SendDataModel>(context, listen: false).displayImageVideo());
          final VideoPlayerController vcontroller =
            VideoPlayerController.file(File(Provider.of<SendDataModel>(context, listen: false).displayImageVideo()));
          videoPlayerListener = () {
            if (videoController != null && videoController.value.size != null) {
              if (mounted) setState(() {});
              videoController.removeListener(videoPlayerListener);
            }
          };
          vcontroller.addListener(videoPlayerListener);
          await vcontroller.setLooping(true);
          await vcontroller.initialize();
          await videoController?.dispose();
          if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
              //saveImagePath = null;
              videoController = vcontroller;
            });
          }
          await vcontroller.play();
        }  //startVideoPlayer
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the function from [`initState()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html). `initState()` is called only once when the `StatefulWidget` is inserted into the Widget tree, so it's a good place to initialize variables or do what you're trying to do.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Do anything you need done here
    _startVideoPlayer();

    // If you want a slight delay, use Future.delayed

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (){
        _startVideoPlayer();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    // rest of app
```